# Swagger Error creating bean with name 'apiDocumentationScanner' defined in URL

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I can't add swagger to my project.
I can share information if you need anything.
Thank you to everyone who has already watched.
I also tried version 3.0.0, but still the problem could not be solved
[image]

[image]

```
2023-07-27T21:03:45.819+03:00  WARN 9932 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'apiDocumentationScanner' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/90539/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.9.2/springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/scanners/ApiDocumentationScanner.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'apiListingScanner' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/90539/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.9.2/springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/scanners/ApiListingScanner.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'apiDescriptionReader' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/90539/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.9.2/springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/scanners/ApiDescriptionReader.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'cachingOperationReader' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/90539/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.9.2/springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/scanners/CachingOperationReader.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'apiOperationReader' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/90539/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.9.2/springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/readers/operation/ApiOperationReader.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'documentationPluginsManager': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'documentationPlugins': Error creating bean with name 'documentationPluginRegistry': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i recommend you to use springdoc-openapi instead of springfox-swagger2, becouse SpringFox is for all intents and purposes dead / abandoned project.
[springdoc-openapi Migration Guide](https://springdoc.org/migrating-from-springfox.html),
but in your case is a good start and it will work great.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. My project could not progress due to errors, now I will revise it immediately.